# Inserting rows in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, mariadb

I am doing the following `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO Elements
(EventID, TypeID) 
SELECT EventID, 2
FROM Elements
Where TypeID = 1
```

i.e. inserting the Elements rows in the same table with another TypeID. It works OK.

But the problem occurs in case some of that rows already exist with `TypeID = 2`. In this case I want just to skip `INSERT` for such rows and continue.

`INSERT IGNORE` doesn't work for me because I don't have unique or something else for these columns. What can I do?

Comment: So are you saying that you cannot use a unique index?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, there is no such index in this table. If there is no other solution, I can probably add index before query and delete after it?

Comment: Why not keep the unique index there permanently so you can continue to use it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think unique index helped me, will you post this solution? Any way, thanks :)

Comment: I gave you a response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here is to add a unique index and then perform your inserts using `INSERT IGNORE ... INTO`:

```
ALTER TABLE Elements ADD UNIQUE unique_index (EventID, TypeID)

INSERT IGNORE INTO Elements (EventID, TypeID) 
SELECT EventID, 2
FROM Elements
WHERE TypeID = 1
```

This insert would fail if the `EventID`, `TypeID` pair of values already existed in the `Elements` table.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at GROUP BY and HAVING in specification

```
INSERT INTO Elements
(EventID, TypeID) 
SELECT EventID, 2
FROM Elements
GROUP BY EventID
HAVING MAX(TypeID)=1
```

Comment: Caution.  The `MAX` is making some assumptions that are not yet stated.